# Break out nested data within SQL, criteria across multiple rows (similar to dcast in R)

Tags: sql, pivot, varchar, self-join

I'm trying to write a simple query to take a data set that looks like this:

```
    ID  |  Col2
    X      B 
    X      C
    Y      B
    Y      D
```

and return this:

```
    ID | Col2 | Col3
    X    B      C
    Y    B      D
```

Essentially, I have an ID column that can have either B, C, or D in Col2. I am trying to identify which IDs only have B and D. I have a query to find both, but not only that combination. Query:

```
select ID, Col2
from Table1
where ID in (
  select ID from Table1
  group by ID
  having count(distinct Col2) = 2) 
order by ID
```

Alternatively, I could use help in finding a way to filter that query on B and D and leave off B and C. I have seen perhaps a self join, but am not sure how to implement that.

Thanks!

EDIT: Most of the data set has, for a given ID, all three of B, C, and D. The goal here is to isolate the IDs that are missing one, namely missing C.

Comment: Sounds like you should look into [PIVOT](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/).  You can filter your results within that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to identify which IDs only have B and D. I have a query to find both

If this is what you want, you don't need multiple columns:

```
select id
from table1
where col2 in ('B', 'D')
group by id
having count(distinct col2) = 2;
```

If you want *only* `'B'` and `'D'` and no others, then:

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having sum(case when col2 = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 AND
       sum(case when col2 = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 AND
       sum(case when col2 not in ('B', 'D') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If there are only two columns, you can also easily pivot the values using aggregation:

```
select id, min(col2), nullif(max(col2), min(col2))
from table1
group by id;
```

Comment: I will edit my post, as I failed to clarify something. Take an ID, say, X. Under X there are instances of B, C, and D. Not just B&C or B&D. I tried what you have there but was still not getting what I wanted, As when I look at the whole data set filtered on "WHERE ID = [result of that query]" I still get records with B, C, and D.

Will the MIN/MAX function do anything on varchar columns?

Comment: @etotheeyepi . . . I added another option in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm still getting IDs that have all three of B, C, and D with that new method.

Comment: @etotheeyepi . . . I left out one condition.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much for all the help.